# Filter factor levels in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

This is the glimpse() of my dataframe DF:

```
Observations: 221184
Variables:
$ Epsilon    (fctr) 96002.txt, 96002.txt, 96004.txt, 96004.txt, 96005.txt, 960...
$ Value   (int) 61914, 61887, 61680, 61649, 61776, 61800, 61753, 61725, 616...
```

I want to filter (remove) all the observations with the first two levels of Epsilon using dplyr.

I mean:

```
DF %>% filter(Epsilon != "96002.txt" & Epsilon != "96004.txt")
```

However, I don't want to use the string values (i.e., "96002.txt" and "96004.txt") but the level orders (i.e., 1 and 2), because it should be a general instruction independent of the level values.

Comment: Is `filter(as.numeric(Epsilon)>2)` what you are looking for?

Comment: @nicola Great, it is! Please rewrite it as an answer (not a comment) and I will accept it.

Comment: As commented by nicola, you can convert `factor`s to their numeric/integer representation just by applying `as.numeric` or `as.integer` on them (which often causes confusion when it's not inteded).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can easily convert a `factor` into an `integer` and then use conditions on it. Just replace your `filter` statement with:

```
 filter(as.integer(Epsilon)>2)
```

More generally, if you have a vector of indices level you want to eliminate, you can try:

```
 #some random levels we don't want
 nonWantedLevels<-c(5,6,9,12,13)
 #just the filter part
 filter(!as.integer(Epsilon) %in% nonWantedLevels)
```

Comment: Is ```as.integer()``` better/safer than ```as.numeric``` here?

Comment: Very slightly more efficient, since a `factor` is internally an `integer` and `numeric` coerces to a float value.